# Getting cartesian product after mapping from another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two datasets called **mydata** and **pairs** respectively,

I want to get all combinations of `id` column from **mydata** with respect to the **pairs** by matching `Value` column in **mydata**. One way to achieve this is ,

```
lapply(1:nrow(pairs),function(ind) {expand.grid(mydata[mydata[,2]==pairs[ind,"a"],1],
                                    mydata[mydata[,2]==pairs[ind,"b"],1])
                                            } )
```

However I feel there must exist more efficient alternatives. Maybe some sort of mapping?
(*I am not asking for efficiency like* `expand.grid` *vs* `data.table::CJ`)

Thank you in advance.

**Data:**

```
mydata <- structure(list(id = 1:40, Value = c(230, 27, 161, 19, 40, 157, 
237, 237, 237, 61, 40, 27, 237, 230, 237, 157, 27, 157, 230, 
157, 19, 161, 61, 27, 61, 61, 237, 157, 27, 40, 27, 40, 40, 61, 
157, 61, 157, 40, 237, 19)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))

pairs <- structure(list(a = c(40, 61, 157), b = c(161, 237, 27)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use `data.table` to get the vectors being passed to `expand.grid` all in one go:

```
library(data.table)

dtPairs <- data.table(Value = unlist(pairs), expand.grid(ind1 = 1:nrow(pairs), ind2 = 1:ncol(pairs)))
dt <- as.data.table(mydata)[Value %in% dtPairs$Value, list(list(id)), by = Value]
dt[dtPairs, `:=`(ind1 = i.ind1, ind2 = i.ind2), on = "Value"]
setorder(dt, ind1, ind2)
ans2 <- lapply(dt[, list(list(V1)), by = ind1]$V1, expand.grid)
```

This involves a lot of overhead, so there won't be performance gains until the dataset gets much larger.

```
fwithDT <- function(data, pairs) {
  dtPairs <- data.table(Value = unlist(pairs), expand.grid(ind1 = 1:nrow(pairs), ind2 = 1:ncol(pairs)))
  return(lapply(setorder(as.data.table(data)[Value %in% dtPairs$Value, list(list(id)), by = Value][dtPairs, `:=`(ind1 = i.ind1, ind2 = i.ind2), on = "Value"], ind1, ind2)[, list(list(V1)), by = ind1]$V1, expand.grid))
}

fOP <- function(data, pairs) {
  return(lapply(1:nrow(pairs),function(ind) {expand.grid(data[data[,2]==pairs[ind,"a"],1],data[data[,2]==pairs[ind,"b"],1])}))
}

mydata2 <- mydata[rep(seq_len(nrow(mydata)), 1001), ]
mydata2[, "Value"] <- mydata2[, "Value"] + rep(seq(0, 1e6, 1e3), each = nrow(mydata))
pairs2 <- pairs[rep(seq_len(nrow(pairs)), 1001), ] + rep(seq(0, 1e6, 1e3), each = 3)

> microbenchmark(ans1 <- fOP(mydata, pairs), ans2 <- fwithDT(mydata, pairs))
Unit: microseconds
                           expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
     ans1 <- fOP(mydata, pairs)  437.3  479.55  599.969  521.75  574.4  5875.2   100
 ans2 <- fwithDT(mydata, pairs) 4537.5 4824.90 5187.012 5039.95 5301.1 13231.2   100

> microbenchmark(ans1 <- fOP(mydata2, pairs2), ans2 <- fwithDT(mydata2, pairs2), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
                             expr       min        lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
     ans1 <- fOP(mydata2, pairs2) 1640.9651 1727.1139 1755.6726 1742.130 1769.235 1958.2109    10
 ans2 <- fwithDT(mydata2, pairs2)  306.3268  318.5617  334.1244  326.865  345.444  376.8728    10

> identical(ans1, ans2)
[1] TRUE
```